# How to get Info from a Web app database into your Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, database

Say I have a rails webapp and I want to make a mobile app version of it; how would I get information from the webapp active record database and implement it in the Android app? And how would I post information to the web server so that I be added to the database.

Let me know if I am not clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I am asking for future proof. To know if I need to do anything special while making my Web app.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are different ways to do it but it is common for mobile apps to consume apis through json.